# grouping multiple tags into one with asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am doing documentation in my asciidoc, I have many items like this

```
# tag::checklist[]
[IMPORTANT.checklist,caption=Checklist]
====
this is the tagged checklist item
====
# end::checklist[]
```

is there a way where i can combine this into a more, syntax friendly macro, for lack of a better term, to have syntax like this

```
[checklist]
====
this is the tagged checklist item
====
```

that renders the same thing?

Oh, and i need this to work for docbook and pdf as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with native Asciidoctor. You would need to write an extension to handle `[checklist]` blocks and emit the appropriate output for the kind of output backend currently in use.

Normally, the `tag::` and `end::` are used block delimiters for included files, which typically would be non-Asciidoc source (think code samples). Since these wrap Asciidoc source, you might consider separating each wrapped block into a separate file, and include them as needed. Doing so would remove the need for the delimiters, and simplify your `include:` macros that involve this content. It would also simplify the work your potential extension would need to perform.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of.  Most of the reason for doing this is to make the raw asciidoc readable and easy.  My problem with the tags is that i do use them with includes.  I have additional pages that pull all the checklist items on a page and build out an actual checklist page.  Lots of work ahead of me i guess